# Get New Page Likes from a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

How to get the "New Page Likes" from a Facebook page?

For example, for the following page:
https://www.facebook.com/Google/likes/

I can get the "People Talking About" by using following URL:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20talking_about_count%20%20from%20page%20where%20username=%27Google%27
```

And I can also get the "Total Page Likes", by using the following URL:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20fan_count%20%20from%20page%20where%20username=%27Google%27
```

Now, how do I get the "New Page Likes"?
Please refer the image "[Google Facebook Likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6XQQ.png)", I have marked it with red box.

Comment: Please eleborate. By new likes you mean likes you have'nt seen yet or the new likes within a week/month etc?

Comment: @SalmanAslam I have mentioned in the question, to refer the image, I have marked with red box on the screenshot. Whatever the "New Page Likes" are on the page [https://www.facebook.com/Google/likes/](https://www.facebook.com/Google/likes/), I need that.. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page-id}?fields=new_like_count&access_token={page-access_token}
```

new_like_count  is page field and its detail is:

Type: unsigned int32

Description: The number of people who have liked the Page, since the last login. ***Only visible to a page admin***

You will get in result:

```
{
    "new_like_count":100 ,
    "id": "123456789"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a deprecated API endpoint which can vanish instantly. The recommended way is to use the Graph API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

The call would be

`https://graph.facebook.com/Google?fields=id,name,likes,talking_about_count&access_token={your_app_access_token}`

If you aren't the page admin, you can't get the `insights` metric `page_fan_adds` which means you need to calculate the daily delta yourself by requesting the count on t0 and again on t1.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights#page_users

Comment: Can you tell me how can I get the delta by requesting the count on t0?

Comment: t0 means the day before t1, which means you need to run the same query twice on both occasions